# Remove Duplicates when column data is in Drop Down List

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, data-validation

I would like to create a dropdown list and make it remove duplicates from the table column where it draws the data from

Given a Table in sheet1 as shown in the figure below.
[image]

In Sheet2 I need a dropdown that but without any duplicates so ideally my drop down list will have just the 6 unique names on the table.

These names should only come up if the Status column of the adjoining name is "In progress" or "Defaulting".

I will possibly like to do this without helper columns but if there is no work around then so be it. I am also open to VBA solutions since I am just starting to delve into VBA but any VBA solutions should please come with a detailed explanation to help a newbie like myself.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see your image on my work PC, but have you tried a pivot table with slicers? Try searching for pivots with slicers and see if that gets you moving in the right direction.

Comment: @jrichall sorry for the very delayed response I have been working on some other projects. So how do I explain this further? Say I have a table column with the name as **Name** with the following data `John, Jane, James, John` and the adjacent column with the name as **Status** and the corresponding data for the names are `Yes, No, Wait, No`. I want all the names in the column to appear as a drop down in another cell but without the duplicates (i.e. I will only have `John, Jane and James` in my drop-down) but If and only If the corresponding status isn't `Yes`.